# EF self tracking Silverlight WCf

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

Hi
I have a silverlight4 + .net 4.0 application where i am using self tracking entities.
In the application i have a silverlight project which contains the entities generated by EF self tracking template.
This project is being shared by the wcf service and the client so that the change tracking works. 
everything builds fine but when i run my service is get the exception
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

any help is much appretiated

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to create a separate project with the entities which was mapped to client side . So 2 projects with contain the same entities. One is mapped to server and one mapped to client and each using different versions of Serialization dll

Answer (score 0):

Correct version for Silverlight and probably also for STEs assmebly is:

```
// Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization, Version 2.0.5.0
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll 
Name: System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e 
Type: Library
```

If you have referenced v2.0.50727 you haven't loaded silverlight version but .NET 2.0 version which will have signiture like:

```
// Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization, Version 2.0.0.0
Location: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll 
Name: System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Type: Library
```

Comment: tried the approach u mentioned but i could not make it to work . Had to create a separate project with the entities which was mapped to client side . So 2 projects with contain the same entities. One is mapped to server and one mapped to client and each using different versions of Serialization dll.