# EF 4.0 Hibernate like saveupdate

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework-4

I have silverlight application, where I use Entity Framework(PostgreSQL) and WCF(not RIA).
Here is the problem:

in database I have table organization and table of contacts. Organization has set of contacts.

EF entity is not a data contract used by wcf. I use convertor to make datacontract from entity and vice versa. So my question is how to save related entities like hibernate saveupdate(cascade="save-update")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't have cascade updates. You [must manually handle changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635071/update-relationships-when-saving-changes-of-ef4-poco-objects/3635326#3635326) = you must manually decide which contracts were modified, which were added and also wich were deleted. MS decided to solve this inconvinience by introducing [Self tracking entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091974/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-tracking-entities/5092097#5092097) but they are not always [bullet proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814706/self-tracking-entities-vs-poco-entities/3815968#3815968) and are [harder to use in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533124/ef-self-tracking-silverlight-wcf/5535209#5535209) because STEs code must be shared among client and server.